# How to replace default Realm with another Realm downloaded from iCloud

Tags: realm

My app uses CloudKit to backup the realm data and fetch the data whenever user press a certain button.
I coded to upload "default.realm" file from documents folder to iCloud with below code.
And the data seems to be uploaded well.

```
// create file path from app's documents folder
NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* fileName = @"default.realm";
NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:kRecordName];
CKRecord *record = [[CKRecord alloc] initWithRecordType:kRecordType recordID:recordID];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
    CKAsset *asset = [[CKAsset alloc] initWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileAtPath]];
    [record setObject:asset forKey:@"Realm"];
}

// upload
CKDatabase *privateDatabase = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] privateCloudDatabase];
[privateDatabase saveRecord:record completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
    // completion handling
}
```

And below is the download part. I can download as well but seems like the realm file is not replaced.

```
CKDatabase *privateDatabase = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] privateCloudDatabase];
CKRecordID *recordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:kRecordName];

// fetch realm from cloud
[privateDatabase fetchRecordWithID:recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
        CKAsset *realmAsset = record[@"Realm"];
        NSData *realmData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:realmAsset.fileURL];
        NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* fileName = @"default.realm";
        NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        // delete existing default.realm file in documents
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:fileAtPath error:&error];
        }
        // create a new default.realm file with downloaded data
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileAtPath contents:realmData attributes:nil]) {
              // code goes thru here but nothing changes
        }
    }
}];
```

I want to replace the entire realm file. What am I doing wrong? Where should I start from?
Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change Realm file path, set to the path to `Realm.Configuration.fileURL`.

```
let fileURL = ...
let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: fileURL)

let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

If you'd not like to specify file path every time, you can set the configuration object as a default configuration.

```
let fileURL = ...
let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: fileURL)

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

let realm = try! Realm()
```

See also https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-configuration

Based on these, to swap Realm files at run-time is very dangerous. To achieve this, you have to guarantee there are no Realm's strong references at all. Instead of this, you can create another file and switch to using it.

```
// fetch realm from cloud
[privateDatabase fetchRecordWithID:recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *record, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
        CKAsset *realmAsset = record[@"Realm"];
        ...

        // Do not delete existing default.realm file in documents

        // create a new default.realm file with downloaded data
        // as deferent file name

        NSString* newFileName = @"default1.realm"; // default2.realm, default3.realm, ...
        NSString* newfileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:newfileAtPath];
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:newfileAtPath contents:realmData attributes:nil]) {
              // Switch to using new file to create Realm instance
              // e.g. set new file path to de default configuration file URL
              let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: newfileAtPath)!)
              Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
              ...
        }
```

Comment: Following your guide, I could swap the realm file without changing the name. Seems like no strong references it had. Thank you so much, you saved my day!